# When you are making an iPhone app using Xcode, how to you get a keyboard to work?

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard

I have a editable text box and when I click on it I get a keyboard. But, it won't let me close out of the keyboard. When I go into the properties of the editable text object ( the Text View object ) and make the return button "Done" it still won't let me exit out.

Comment: I should probably say more... I have a utility app with a main window and a flip-side window. The keyboard is in the main window.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it programatically, by using **resignFirstResponder** message on the UITextField is currently being edited with the keyboard. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389825/dismiss-iphone-keyboard) Stack Overflow question on the issue.

Comment: I'm new to this, so I don't know where to put the code you just said. But I'll check out the link thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what they were saying because i'm new. But I guess I can go on the apple website to see what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you controller is a UITextField Delegate in your .h- something like this:

```
@interface UserAddEditController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

2nd, you need  to implement the following:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

Finally, make sure your UITextField's delegate is set to your File Owner in interface builder.

That should do it!