# iPhone: Resign Keyboard with Done button action with XIB

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

hi i am working on UITextview

how to Resign Keyboard, after keyboard "Done button" click Action, which XIB

Thank you

Comment: - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:   (NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
 // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
  
  // Be sure to test for equality using the "isEqualToString" message
         [textView resignFirstResponder];
  
  // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
  return NO;
    }
 
 // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return YES;
} //CHECK THIS IT WORKS FOR YOU

Comment: if your comment is the solution you've ended with, you should instead post it as an answer and mark that, otherwise pick one of the answers below. I vote for @Robotic_Cat because his solution worked for me. However, @WrightCS's solution is also good for more fine-grain control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

hi if you want answer for, Resign the keyboard of UITextview with default "Done" button on keyboard, then this is answer for that

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        // Be sure to test for equality using the "isEqualToString" message

        [textView resignFirstResponder];

        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added

        return NO;
    }

    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view

    return YES;
}
```

i followed this to resign keyboard of UITextview, if there is any concern inform me

Thank You

Comment: for UITextField use this instead: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)text{        
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {        
        [textField resignFirstResponder];        
        return NO;
    }    
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 9):

Create an `IBAction` and in IB hook it up to the `UITextfield`'s `DidEndOnExit` event. Then call the `[textViewName resignFirstResponder]` to make the keyboard go away.

Alternatively, try using `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in the IBAction.

Comment: This is actually the only answer for the original poster's actual question although the other methods will also dismiss the keyboard. The original poster asked for a way in the nib to connect an action to be executed when the 'done' button is pressed. This answer explains how to do that.

Comment: This seems a better solution than the one accepted as an answer, which is checking every character input

Answer (score 4):

To assign the action to the `Done` button of a keyboard:

*In these examples, `myTextView` is a `UITextView` that is defined in the header and connected in Interface Builder.*

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView*)textView {
    if (textView == myTextView) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

To assign it to an external button:

Be sure to define an `IBAction` in your header, then in Interface Builder, connect the button to this action for `touchUpInside:`

### .h

```
-(IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender;
```

### .m

```
-(IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {

    [myTextView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: There is no such delegate method:-(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView*)textView

Comment: I must correct you. There is such a method and WrightCS is correct here as you can see in this other post as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389825/dismiss-iphone-keyboard

Comment: No there isn't. There is a `textFieldShouldReturn` method for `UITextField`, but no similar method for `UITextView`. Please check your facts.

Answer (score 0):

Call `resignFirstResponder` on the textview that has focus in order to dismiss the keyboard.