# ios remove keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, focus, uidatepicker, iphone-keypad

I have some text edit fields, and also a button to show a uidatepicker.. if I go to the uitextedit, the keyboard appears, but when I click the button, the keyboard is still here...
how can I remove it?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `resignFirstResponder`, see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750606/iphone-resign-keyboard-with-done-button-action-with-xib/4750985#4750985).

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: thanks, the code I found is this: [self.view endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 5):

See this answer for the easiest way to do it: [Easy way to dismiss keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard)

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `-resignFirstResponder` on your currently-editing text field.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where I don't have direct access to the 'first responder', so I tend to use a different approach.
I have a utility class for the keyboard with, among other functions, this one:

```
+ (BOOL)dismiss:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view.isFirstResponder) {
        [view resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
        if ([Keyboard dismiss:subView]) // It's calling itself, just to be perfectly clear
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This lets me simply call for example: `[Keyboard dismiss:self.view]` from anywhere within a `UIViewController`.