# how can I dismiss keyboard on Enter keypress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard, enter

I want to dismiss my keyboard as I press RETURN key.

I have tried by putting button in view's back side.

But how can I do this by pressing RETURN key?

Comment: Where is an Enter key on iPhone?)

Comment: i hope you mean the done/return button ? No enter key on iphone/ipad

Comment: do some research first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389825/dismiss-iphone-keyboard

Comment: I have searched...And ENTER key from my PC keyboard

Comment: @KhushbuShah: I think you need to post the question with respect to device and not the simulator :) . This is a common mistake as you are a fresher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to add the delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`

Answer (score 3):

I'm presuming you're talking about a `UITextField` rather than a `UITextView` as your question isn't that clear? If so then ensure your class is marked as a `UITextFieldDelegate` in the interface file,

```
@interface MyController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
   UITextField *activeTextField;

   // ...remainder of code not show ...
}
```

and then you should implement the two delegate methods as below,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    activeTextField = textField;!    
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    activeTextField = nil; 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

However if you're using a `UITextView` then things are a bit more complicated. The `UITextViewDelegate` protocol lacks the equivalent to the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method, presumably since we shouldn’t expect the Return key to be a signal that the user wishes to stop editing the text in a multi-line text entry dialog (after all, the user may want to insert line breaks by pressing Return).

However, there are several ways around the inability of the `UITextView` to resign as first responder using the keyboard. The usual method is to place a *Done* button in the navigation bar when the `UITextView` presents the pop-up keyboard. When tapped, this button asks the text view to resign as first responder, which will then dismiss the keyboard.

However, depending on how you’ve planned out your interface, you might want the `UITextView` to resign when the user taps outside the `UITextView` itself. To do this, you’d subclass `UIView` to accept touches, and then instruct the text view to resign when the user taps outside the view itself.

Create a new class,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView {
   IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
}

@end
```

Then, in the implementation, implement the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method and ask the `UITextView` to resign as first responder.

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touches began count %d, %@", [touches count], touches);

    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Once you’ve added the class, you need to save all your changes, then go into Interface Builder and click on your view. Open the Identity inspector in the Utility pabel and change the type of the view in your *nib* file to be your `CustomView` rather than the default `UIView` class. Then in the Connections Inspector, drag the `textView` outlet to the `UITextView`. After doing so, and once you rebuild your application, touches outside the active UI elements will now dismiss the keyboard. Note however that if the `UIView` you are subclassing is “behind” other UI elements, these elements will intercept the touches before they reach the UIView layer. So while this solution is elegant, it can be used in only some situations. In many cases, you’ll have to resort to the brute force method of adding a *Done* button to the navigation bar to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have done `UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>` and `yourTextField.delegate=self`;

and then in the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
{

   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your view controller class is a delegate for your `UITextField` and then use the delegate method in that class:

```
#pragma mark - Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    // Dismiss the keyboard when the Return key is pressed.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```