# Using the 'Done' button as the return key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to know if it would be possible to use the 'Done' key of the keyboard as the return key ?

**Example :**

You are in a search field, you type whatever you want to search for and then instead of tapping on the return key of the keyboard, I would like the user to be able to start the search by tapping on the 'Done' key juste above the keyboard.

**Update :**

I don't want to change the text or the aspect of the return key. I want to launch the search with the 'Done' blue button that is in the small bar above the keyboard, next to 'Previous' and 'Next'

Comment: do you mind providing a bit more information?

Comment: No I don't, I just thought it was enough

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1185197/919545 try searching a bit more next time

Comment: what if this is not what I need at all ?

Comment: 4 down votes because you didn't understand the problem. Maybe this forum isn't about helping people anymore..

Comment: That DONE-button you are referring to, is not part of the actual keyboard but is placed inside an additional view (you built yourself) and assigned to the inputAccessoryView, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I just implement the following method:

from UITextFieldDelegate

```
textFieldShouldReturn:
```

Asks the delegate if the text field should process the pressing of the return button.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Add this to your text field's delegate to remove the keyboard when it's pressed:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextfield {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
   It will help you...
First set delegate to your all textfields than write this method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```