# Unable to dismiss keyboard in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I cannot get textFieldShouldEndEditing to call. I have re created the links in interface builder and tried, but nothing seems to work. Any idea why this would not be called?

Edit

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     NSLog(@"Done editing...");
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Set delegate in interfacebuilder

Comment: Does `Done editing...` show up in the logs?

Comment: No it does not shoes Done editing i have added 3 textfeild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code .

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
 [Self.view EndEditing:YES];
 return YES;    
}
```

Also use   `_myTextField.delegate = self`; in your  `ViewDidLoad`

And in your .h file, add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` after the name of your class.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code ...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
 return YES;    
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  return YES;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need the delegate!

Try to add in your .h this `<UITextFieldDelegate>`

and in your .m

`_yourTextField.delegate = self`.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your textField's delegate to the class where you implemented `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`.

You can do it two ways :

First, in InterfaceBuilder, ctrl-drag from the component to the viewController, and select "delegate".

Or, in the `viewDidLoad` of the class, add this line :

```
_myTextField.delegate = self;
```

For both ways, in your .h file, add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` after the name of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun if you want to be really fancy, you can have keyboard disappear whenever user touches anywhere on the screen. Add this code in ViewDidLoad and it will work.

Read this Stackoverflow link too - [Dismiss iphone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389825/dismiss-iphone-keyboard)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
//here text1 is your custom UITextField
    [text1 resignFirstResponder];
}
```