# How would i close keyboards UITextField

Tags: objective-c

i am wondering how i would handle closing keyboard in UITextField, i know how to do it when i do it via Outlets, but now i am declaring my textfields in code like this:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 185, 30)];
playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
if([indexPath row] == 0) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Server Address";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} else if([indexPath row] == 1){
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Server Port";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} else {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    playerTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
}

playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
playerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
playerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
playerTextField.tag = 0;

playerTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
[playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

[cell.contentView addSubview:playerTextField];


return cell;
}
```

How would i manage that?

Comment: Just do;
[textField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Do it whenever certain event occurs or you need to keep track of your currently active textfield. The other idea would be to loop through all the root views and then ask the view if it is firstResponder using method isFirstResponder and then resignFirstResponder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dismiss iphone keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389825/dismiss-iphone-keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your textfield is inside a cell, you need to tag it, which you already are, however i would recommend using something different than `0`. then whenever you need to resign it (assuming you know which cell to look for) :

```
    UITextField *myField = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myRow inSection:mySection]].contentView viewWithTag:myTag];
    [myField resignFirstResponder];
```

if you dont know which cell it is then youll need to loop through all the cells.

hope this helps

Comment: I dont quite understand your code, where would i put that? And where would i get mySection and myRow from?

Comment: well in your case you have only one section `0` and three rows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have many textFields, one in each cell?

You need to add property `@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *currentTextField`

In your textField creation method you'll want to set table view controller as text field delegate:

```
playerTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then you have to make your tableViewController implement UITextFieldDelegate protocol (add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` after you class name in header file), and then add implementation for this method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     self.currentTextField = textField;
}
```

That means when one of textFields starts editing, it gets tracked.

Probably you have event or button which would call something like `(void)save` action.
Add to its implementation:

```
- (void)save {
     [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You can also track when did textField finish editing: `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`